# advance admin generator symfony2

Tags: symfony, admin, generator, sonata-admin, sylius

At the company where I'm working we want to create a complex admin for a new project. We have the following requirements:

- Should restrict the list of objects an user has access.
- Have a log of changes to the entities.
- Permisions based on role of user and group he belongs (think for goup as organization). The user can manage entities that are created by users of the same organization. When a entity is created, a owner is assigned.
- RESTfull

We considered SonataAdmin, EasyAdmin or creating an admin with SyliusResourceBundle and SyliusGridBundle.

The questions for SonataAdmin and EesyAdmin are if it is easy to manage permissions based on roles and the organization the user belongs to. Also, we are not sure if it will be complex to made it able to make it RESTfull.

Our questions regarding to SyliusResourceBundle and SyliusGridBundle are if it is too complex to create an admin generator with this two components. On the other hand we think it is more flexible on configuring to use custom managers (to envolve the repositories) in SyliusResourceBundle then SonataAdmin and EasyAdmin. Is that true?

What do you thing of this options? Are there other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only answer the first of your questions. Will be not easy to implement this future on EasyAdmin and as it's owner say to me:

> "If this feature is essential to your backend, I recommend you to use
>   SonataAdminBundle instead"

This are some post when you can find some clues about how to do it [here](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/885), [here](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1040) and [here](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1076). You can see the intention of it's owner to develop this feature in the near future,but not ready yet, so Sonata still remain as the best option. The problem with sonata is that still isn't fully compatible with symfony3 in an stable version, so it's only recommended with symfony 2.7.

Hope this information help you.